# How to link same page with two urls in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to show the city name in the url before page name if the user is searching for a specific city, and if the user is not searching for a specific city then I want to show the normal url. How can we achieve this in Next Js.

Ex.

```
     http://localhost:3000/Delhi/furniture
     http://localhost:3000/furniture
```

Both the urls should point to same page.

I tried with  next/link component.

```
<Link href='/furniture' as={config.city ? config.city + '/furniture': 'furniture'}><a>Furniture</a></Link>
```

Link has two props href and as. Using as we can show different url than the actual url but if you directly hit the url which is changed by 'as' prop it will show 404 page not found. I could not find any porp or feature using which I can achieve the above.

Comment: I think you should at a minimum render the page on one of the routes, and redirect to that route from the other, or render the same component on both routes. What have you tried already? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 10):

You could use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) in your `next.config.js` to map the paths containing a city to the `furniture` route.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    async rewrites() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/:city/furniture',
                destination: '/furniture'
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

You can also add [regex path matching](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#regex-path-matching) to allow matching only certain values for `:city`.

Comment: Is there a way to get access to the query param which was selected? `:city`? It looks like it's lost in the path or query! I still can see it in the `asPath`. But I think making one regexp is not optimal

Comment: @joseglego It should be available in  `router.query` too.